# Running iPython Notebook in Docker container on Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

How do I run and access iPython Notebook (in Docker on EC2) from the browser?

This is what I tried:

- From EC2 Quick Start menu, selected Amazon Linux AMI 2015.03 on t2.micro instance.
- Everything left as default, except 3 rules created for "Configure Security Group":

  - Type: "SSH"; Protocol: "TCP"; Port Range: "22"; Source: "Anywhere";
  - Type: "HTTPS"; Protocol: "TCP"; Port Range: "443"; Source: "Anywhere";
  - Type: "Custom TCP Rule"; Protocol: "TCP"; Port Range: "8888"; Source: "Anywhere";
- After SSH'ing to instance:

  ```
  $ sudo yum install -y docker ; sudo service docker start

  $ sudo docker pull continuumio/miniconda # Anaconda includes iPython Notebook

  $ sudo docker run -it -p 8888:8888 continuumio/miniconda ipython notebook
  ```
- Then launching browser to https://ec2-xx-x-x-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8888 didn't work.

Answer (score -2):

I wouldn't be too comfortable opening 443 and 8888 on the Internet for my EC2 instances. My common setup is Anaconda on an Ubuntu box.

I usually ssh port forward my ipython notebook sessions to my localhost on my macbook with this ssh command:

```
ssh -i myPrivateSSHKey.pem ubuntu@54.1.2.3 -L 8888:localhost:8888
```

Then I open Chrome and request URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888
```